# How to make JavaScript signup validation work with example.php file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, validation

I have setup a MySQL database to maintain data for login and registration. Now I want to write javascript validations for my signup form

I did some research on Javascript and ajax validation. My understanding is that you can have both javascript and ajax validation on server side for security reasons. But one can also have just js validation?

My register.php looks like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <form action="register.php" method="post" id="form" name="form">

        <table width="35%">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>


                <td><input type="text" name="name" ></td>
                <div id="username_error"></div>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>


                <td><input type="email" name="email"  ></td>
                <div id="email_error"></div>

            </tr>

            <td>Password</td>


            <td><input type="password" name="password" ></td>
            <div id="password_error"></div>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Register" onSubmit="myFunction()"></td>
    
            </tr>
        </table>
        <a href="login.php">Login</a>
```

This lines of code is just something I was experimenting with for displaying error messages:

```html
<div id="username_error"></div>
<div id="email_error"></div>
<div id="password_error"></div>
```

This is my script.js

```js
let name = document.querySelector("#name")
let email = document.querySelector("#email")
let password = document.querySelector("#password")
let passVal = '?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]'
let emailVal = '^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/'

function myFunction() {
    if(name == ""){
        alert ( "Please fill in the 'Your Name' box." );

    }
    if(email == emailVal){
        alert ( "Please fill in the 'Your Name' box." );

    }
    if(password == passVal){
        alert ( "Please fill in the 'Your Name' box." );

    }
}
```

Register.php and script.js does not seem to work together. I believe I've set this up right:
`<td><input type="submit" value="Register" onSubmit="myFunction()"></td>` but not sure.

How do I implement my script.js to work with register.php?

Comment: its probably better - especially for starters - to use bootstrap as a framework (take a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/ - it will make your life much easier)

Comment: I odn't understand what you mean by "javascript authentication" if it is something other than ajax.

Comment: When you select the field values for each of your form fields, you are only selecting the HTML elements not getting the actual field value.

Comment: @symcbean I mean javascript validiation, not authentication. So you check every input field in the form and doing if(){} conditions based on what you want to evaluate

Comment: @IvanKahl So do I need to do this? 
let name = document.querySelector("#name").value?

Comment: @sintakonte Well, Im part of group of students and we are creating this webApp. So we have to use javascript, ajax og php and the usual frontend web technologies. I'm not to keen an just using bootstrap just because it's easier. I do really want to learn setting up forms with validations.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your last question: **no**. You can't just have JS validation on the client. Never trust the data that the client gives you. It's easy for even an amateur "hacker" to bypass JS checks and submit whatever data they want.

Validation needs to be done both ends (on the client for UX and on the server to ensure that nothing dangerous gets through).

The reason your function doesn't work is because the variables (name, email, etc.) are being set when the page loads. You need to set the variables inside the function, like so:

```
function myFunction() {
    let name = document.querySelector("#name")
    let email = document.querySelector("#email")
    let password = document.querySelector("#password")
    let passVal = '?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]'
    let emailVal = '^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/'

    if(name == ""){
        alert ( "Please fill in the 'Your Name' box." );

    }
    if(email == emailVal){
        alert ( "Please fill in the 'Your Name' box." );

    }
    if(password == passVal){
        alert ( "Please fill in the 'Your Name' box." );

    }
}
```

Inside the top of your register.php file you need to have a check on the `$_POST` data, and validate it in there too. That is the server side check. Make sure that you **escape** all the data you receive to ensure that you're safe from malicious injections.

Comment: I don't really understand how to setup the check to validate $_POST data. Can you give me an example with my file? I'm really sorry,this is the first time I've tried to do this...

Comment: is it something like this you mean? if(isset($_POST['name'])

Comment: Yes. The `$_POST` variable is a PHP array that your register PHP file will receive when you submit the form (since the form `action` = register.php).

Comment: So this is what I have on top of register.php now. 

        if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
            $name     = $_POST['name'];
            $email    = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
}

*PHP CODE* 

How can I check if this works with my script.js file, since I have the alert messages on there? I have imported the Js script in my register.php:
<script src="script.js"></script>

I have myFunction inside the onclick method:

<td><input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" onclick="myFunction();"></td>

What is left?

Comment: There are a few ways of doing that. But you won't be able to use a script.js file. You'll have to use a `<script>` tag inside your index HTML file. You could try something like `<script>alert("<?php var_dump($_POST) ?>")</script>`. This is very hacky, but when the page loads, PHP will dump the contents of the `$_POST` array into the JS `alert` when you submit the form and the page is reloaded.

Comment: But normally you should just write `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of your PHP file if you're debugging. Much neater. Will just spew the data onto the page.